Looking for a mistake in this proof.
I'm struggling to find the error in the following reasoning :
Let $\mathcal{N}$ denotes the Baire space and $\mathcal{I} = [0,1] - \mathbb{Q}$ the set of irrational in $[0,1]$. It can be shown (with continued fractions for example) that there exists a homeomorphism $\phi : \mathcal{N} \to \mathcal{I}$. Then
\begin{equation}
\psi : (x,y) \in \mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{N} \to (\phi(x),\phi(y)) \in \mathcal{I} \times \mathcal{I}
\end{equation}
is a homeomorphism such that $\textrm{proj}_{\mathcal{I}} \circ \psi = \phi \circ \textrm{proj}_{\mathcal{N}}$ (where $\textrm{proj}_{\mathcal{I}} : (x,y) \in \mathcal{I} \times \mathcal{I} \mapsto x$ and $\textrm{proj}_{\mathcal{N}} : (x,y) \in \mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{N} \mapsto x$)
Now there exists a closed subset $F$ of $\mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{N}$ such that $\textrm{proj}_{\mathcal{N}}(F)$ is not Borel (every analytic subset of $\mathcal{N}$ is the projection of a closed subset of $\mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{N}$). Thus :

$\psi(F)$ is closed.
$\textrm{proj}_{\mathcal{I}} (\psi(F)) = \phi (\textrm{proj}_{\mathcal{N}}(F))$ is not Borel.

As $H = \psi(F)$ is closed in $\mathcal{I} \times \mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{I}$ is a subspace of $[0,1]$, there exists a closed subset $\tilde{H}$ (hence a compact subset) of $[0,1]^2$ such that $H = \tilde{H} - \mathbb{Q}^2$. Now $\tilde{H} = H \sqcup (\tilde{H} \cap \mathbb{Q}^2)$ thus
\begin{equation}
\textrm{proj}_{\mathbb{R}}(\tilde{H}) = \textrm{proj}_{\mathcal{I}}(H) \cup \textrm{proj}_{\mathbb{R}}(\tilde{H} \cap \mathbb{Q}^2).
\end{equation}
But $\textrm{proj}_{\mathbb{R}}(\tilde{H} \cap \mathbb{Q}^2)$ is at most countable and $\textrm{proj}_{\mathbb{R}}(\tilde{H})$ is compact, thus $\textrm{proj}_{\mathcal{I}}(H)$ is a $G_{\delta}$ of $[0,1]$ and thus it is a Borel set of $\mathcal{I}$.
Which is absurd.

The error is in your description of $\tilde{H}$.  It is true that we can find a closed set $\tilde{H} \subseteq [0, 1]^2$ such that $H = \tilde{H} \cap \mathcal{I}^2 = \tilde{H} \cap ([0, 1] \setminus \mathbb{Q})^2$, but $([0, 1] \setminus \mathbb{Q})^2 \neq [0, 1]^2 \setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$, so we can't write this as $H = \tilde{H} \setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$.
This means that to express $\tilde{H}$ we have
$\begin{align*}\tilde{H} &= (\tilde{H} \cap \mathcal{I}^2) \sqcup (\tilde{H} \cap ([0,1]^2 \setminus \mathcal{I}^2)) \\
&= H \sqcup (\tilde{H} \cap ([0, 1]^2 \setminus ([0, 1] \setminus \mathbb{Q})^2)) \\&= H \sqcup (\tilde{H} \cap (\mathbb{Q} \times [0, 1] \cup [0, 1] \times \mathbb{Q})) \end{align*}$
The second term of the union is not countable, so the rest of the argument doesn't follow.

You're right, thank you. It was a stupid mistake after all.
Is the rest of the reasoning right? I was wondering if I'd made a mistake with the different topologies.

I don't see any problem with the rest of it
